# Properly setting the context for an Ember partial rendered from within a template

Tags: ember.js

I have the following parent template

```
{{render 'form' this}}
```

and the following partial template

```
<form>
   ...
</form>
<a href='#' {{action 'cancel'}}>{{buttonTitle}}</a>
```

the `buttonTitle` is coming through from the parent controller but the `cancel` action that is defined in the same controller is not binding. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could you try `target="controller"`?

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe I just tried for both the `render` and the `action` but it doesn't seem to help for either.

Comment: Any error message? How exactly did you try? `<a href='#' {{action cancel target="controller"}}>{{buttonTitle}}</a>`?

Comment: No error messages which is making this difficult to debug. I wrote it as `<a href='#' {{action 'cancel' target='controller'}}>{{buttonTitle}}</a>` and tried without quotes around `cancel` neither works.

Comment: which build of the framework? 1.0-pre2 or latest built from master?

Comment: latest build from master. I just updated my clone from master and rebuilt, no difference :(

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe my app files are here if you'd like to take a look: https://github.com/bcardarella/ember-railsapi/tree/new_router/app/assets/javascripts

Comment: the two files you'll want to look at: `templates/users/new.hbs` and `templates/users/form.hbs`

Comment: I'll have to pause this until perhaps later tonight

Comment: The form template has a small syntax error - extra closing statement in the create button. But that's not why it doesn't work tho

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you want is the `template` helper, which renders templates in the current context.

The `render` helpers renders a template with its associated controller. So for example, if you did:

```
{{render "sidebar"}}
```

That would render the `sidebar` template using `App.SidebarController`.

If you did:

```
{{render "post" post}}
```

That would render the `post` template using `App.PostController`, with the current `post` as the controller's model.

It was a bug that these sub-controllers don't bubble up events, but I don't think that you wanted this behavior in the first place. (**UPDATE** This bug is now fixed [on master](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/ee86cdd68f801444efb11bbe3e06c0ed0e917c2f))

We are planning on making the naming and usages much clearer in the coming weeks.

Comment: thank you for weighing in. This much makes sense but I'm still confused why the `buttonTitle` attribute makes it through the the `cancel` action does not.

Comment: Can you make a JSBin that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Here you go: http://jsbin.com/welcome/73422/edit

As you can see the `linkTitle` attribute is applied but the `back` action is not bound.

Comment: FYI the build of ember I am linking to in my GH repo was built yesterday against 605fcc652cab57b0e86cd8cae665f07f436eed46

Comment: I was able to solve my original problem by doing {{render 'users/form' controller='users.controller'}} but I'll leave the JSFiddle code as-is for now if you wanted to see if what I reproduced is a bug.

Comment: The controller bubbling issue is fixed in https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/ee86cdd68f801444efb11bbe3e06c0ed0e917c2f

Comment: Great, but now I am seeing the opposite. The actions bubble up but the attributes are not. Is this to be expected?

Comment: Honestly, I was surprised that the attributes "bubbled" before. They should not. If you want to share the same context, use `template`, not `render`.